# Purposes of using custom static/dynamic libraries in programming languages

Tags: c++, dll, static, shared-libraries

I am learning c++. So I'm a beginner. But I can't understand why programmers create custom libraries. I can easily get an answer to the question "how", but I can't get an answer to the question Why, I've found two possible reasons:

1. Organizing subprograms (completed code pieces to one library) to use in different programms or tools, for example.
2. Binary output size.

For organizing functional code blocks, I'd prefer to use `git clone` instead of a library. For me, it is a more comfortable way to integrate, edit, and use my code in different projects.

About output size: it's a controversial issue. If I use a static library, I don't get a smaller size because, using a static library, my app will be extended by byte code, but using native code, created code blocks will be converted as machine code and immediately added to the executable file. If we speak about DLLs, yes, you can reduce the output size, but you've got another issue. Loading in RT. I won't get any benefits.

Can you explain to me why?

Comment: Mostly 1. For example, if you fix a bug in a shared library, everyone will be updated.

Comment: At my work, we have at least 4 applications that need to talk with the medical device.  We can either copy the code 4 times or have the comm. code into one library, which is shared among the 4 applications.  The problem with copying the code, is that some applications may not be upgraded when there are changes to the comm. code.

Comment: The C language doesn't come with a linked list or a map.  So, instead of rewriting the code for the data structures for each program, a library is created.  The output size of your program is not controversial.  Libraries have a size.  The library size can be added to your executable length (static library) or added to your package (dynamic library).  It's a matter of how you want to manage the library or the code.  There's a management issue with DLLs so you may want to use static.  However, a dynamic library allows easier updates to your package.

Comment: You will likely get a smaller size with static libraries. For example if you compile the entire boost library as static (>1GiB size) and then your code only uses one of two functions, your binary will only be increased by the size of those funcitons, not the entire size of the library.  With dynamic libraries, you bring everything with you.

Answer (score 0):

You’re **already** writing libraries if you have multiple repositories that can be variously combined to form multiple programs.  (This is an excellent idea: you never know when you’ll want to build a bigger program on top of current capabilities, and libraries compose much better than programs.  What *mechanism* to use to compose source libraries is a different question.)  Compiling them into binary libraries is mostly a matter of **convenience**, either because linking is cheaper than compiling or because it fixes things like preprocessor macros.  It also avoids circumstances where two dependencies might otherwise require multiple copies of a third they both use.